# Python dictionary nested within method auto-executes all values (methods) when outer method is called

Tags: python, class, dictionary, methods, instance

I'm working on a simple skeleton for a game, and in an effort to try and be more "pythonic", I'm using objects/classes/dictionaries to try and capture all my actions/behaviors (as methods over functions, etc).

For some reason, every time I execute the method 'act' within the class "Player", the dictionary embedded within act runs all of its values (which are, in turn, methods from within the same instance of the class "Player").  In other words, the player chooses "attack, heal, and flee" every time, all at once, before being prompted.

I'm sure there's a simple explanation, but I've been looking for hours and can't find another example of someone's dictionary auto-running all the methods embedded within.  Can you help?

Thanks!
- Jake

```
from random import randint

### BEGIN ALL CLASSES HERE

# To be used for all game objects (living and non-living)
class gameObject(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

# To be used for all characters who can act in some way/be killed/change
class livingThing(gameObject):
    def __init__(self, name, HP=1):
        self.name = name
        self.HP = HP

# The playable character(s)
class Player(livingThing):

    def __init__(self,name="The Stranger", HP=4, MP=5, strength=1, intellect=1, spirit=1, luck=5, gil=6):
        self.name = name
        self.HP = HP
        self.MP = MP
        self.gil = gil
        self.strength = strength
        self.intellect = intellect
        self.spirit = spirit
        self.luck = luck

    def act(player, enemy):
        actions = {
        "attack" : player.attack(enemy), 
        "heal" : player.heal(enemy), 
        "flee" : player.flee()
        }
        #Takes input from the player

        decision = input("What would you like to do? ")

        if decision.lower() in actions:
            actions[decision.lower()]
        else:
            print("That didn't work!  Try again.")

    # Prints both player and enemy HP
    def printHP(player, enemy):
        print("{0}'s' HP: {1} \n{2}'s HP: {3}".format(player.name, player.HP, enemy.name, enemy.HP))

    # Allows the player to attack an enemy (currently functional)
    def attack(player, enemy):
        enemy.HP -= player.strength
        print("You strike {0} for {1} damage!".format(enemy.name, player.strength))
        player.printHP(enemy)

    # Allows the player to heal a certain amount of health based on its "spirit" stat (currently functional)
    def heal(player, enemy):
        healed = randint(0, player.spirit)
        player.HP += healed
        print("You've healed for {0}!".format(healed))
        player.printHP(enemy)

    #Allows the player to attempt to run away
    def flee(player):
        randluck = randint(0, player.luck)
        if randluck > 3:
            print("You successfully escaped!")
            return player.HP
        else:
            print("You weren't able to escape!")


# Anything that can act with/against the player
class Actor(livingThing):
    def __init__(self, name="Unknown Entity", HP=10, MP=2, gil=3):
        self. name = name
        self.HP = HP
        self.MP = MP
        self.gil = gil

### END ALL CLASSES ###


### DICTIONARIES CONTAINING ACTIONS ###



### CHARACTERS ###

fighter = Player()

monster = Actor()




fighter.act(monster)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see the problem. When you are executing Python code, and you have a dictionary as you do, Python evaluates the dictionary fully. If you wanted your values (in your key:value) pairs to be the **results** of those methods, this is surely one way to do it.

In your case, what you can do is reference the **function** itself, and not invoke it. You can do this by getting rid of the parentheses, like this:

```
player.attack
```

instead of

```
player.attack()
```

Then, to call the function you can do something like

`actions[decision.lower()](enemy)`

Since one of your functions, *flee*, doesn't accept any parameters, you could give *flee* a parameter that you simply don't use in the function. If you were designing many many methods that your player can *act* with, then one strategy would be to give them all only named parameters, like this:

```
def f1(enemy=None,something=None,foo=None):
    if enemy is None:
         raise Exception("enemy cannot be None")
    #process_enemy
```

If however, you also have a very high amount of parameters, then you could do this:

```
def attack(**kwargs):
    #kwargs is a dictionary of parameters provided to the function
    enemy = kwargs.get('enemy',None)
    if enemy is None:
        raise Exception("enemy cannot be None")

def eat(**kwargs):
    food = kwargs.get('food',None)
    if enemy is None:
        raise Exception("food cannot be None")

attack(enemy="someenemyobject")
eat(food="somefoodobject")

attack()                        # raises Exception
attack(food="somefoodobject")   # raises Exception
food(enemy="someenemyobject")   # raises Exception
food(food="somefoodobject",enemy="someenemyobject") # does not raise Exception
```

Comment: This worked perfectly--thanks for both the answer and the insight!

Comment: @Jake I edited the answer to provide a few more tips on function design, hope it helps!

Comment: These are great suggestions, and I ended up just adding the same arguments (i.e. player and enemy) to the "flee" function and that fixed the (new) issue.

The additional ideas, though, are sure to be helpful as I expand this further!  Thanks again!  ^^

Comment: Python can handle the missing parameters if you define the methods like this: `def attack(self, enemy, **ignored)` and `def flee(self, **ignored)`. No need for manually raising an exception (which should be TypeError and not Exception in this case).

Comment: @Wombatz, this actually also helps--I'm seeing the comment late, but it looks like your addition will solve new problems that have since emerged.  Thanks!